# JavaScript / jQuery concatenating variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

To start with this. I have an associative array named `$body` (PHP).

Let's say I want to get the value of `$body[1]` or `$body[2]`, depending on the `id` of an element.

So here's my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.messages').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#generic-modal-title').html('Message Preview');
    $('#generic-modal-body').html('" . $body[-concatenate id here-] . "');
  });
})"
```

What I tried doing (doesn't work):

```
$('#generic-modal-body').html('" . $body["id"] . "');
```

Comment: To start with JS, there's no associative arrays.

Comment: @Teemu ohh, so I have to use a PHP variable inside the `[ ]`?

Comment: The array $body is a PHP variable.

Comment: Äh ... What? No ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: you should use $('#generic-modal-body').html('<?php echo $body["id"] ?>');

Comment: Thank you for the link, will look at it.

Comment: `<?php echo "var body = ". $body . ";\n"; ?>` inside your script tag should do the trick

Comment: You can't achieve what you want this way. You've to create the possible values into JS, either hardcode them, or make a static array with PHP before loading the page. You can't dynamically execute PHP at client-side. Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out i have tested this working fine as you required

```
<?php $body = array(0 => "content") ?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id  = 0;
  <?php echo "var body = " . json_encode($body) .";"; ?>
  $('#generic-modal-body').html(body[id]);
});

<div id="generic-modal-body"></div>
```